# strange thing in sequential file access

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Recently, I am trying to write codes to get trained in sequential file access. I learned it well, but the issue is kinda stressing me out. I have a code that work 100%, and its task is "make a code that prints array elements inside a file", the text file name is "numric".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[3]={5000,6000,7000};
    ofstream outfile("numric.txt");

    if (outfile.is_open()){
        outfile << "employee payroll:" << endl;

        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
            outfile << a[i] << endl;

        outfile.close();
    } else
        cout << "failed!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I implemented the code in two different program (VS Code, dev++) and it works fine. It found the file, but when I open the text file, there isn't any text inside it. The code should do its work by finding some text inside it if I opened it.

Note:sometimes when the code works, the antivirus pops a message saying it found an item that doesn't look safe in the program and deletes it.

Comment: ***note:sometimes when the code work the anti-vires pops a message saying it found a item that does't looks safe in the program and deletes it.*** You probably already found your problem.  Add an exception for your antivirus. Tell it to not look in the folder where you have your code.

Comment: sounds like you need a better anti-virus program

Comment: Or maybe just uninstall anti-virus programs and learn how to keep your computer clean

Comment: Where did you get your toolset? It's become a more common attack vector for malware authors to put out altered and compromised dev tooling as late. Usually for the paid tools but also unfortunately for the free ones as well.

Comment: I see a contradiction in "I have a code that work 100%" and "it works fine" on the one hand, and "when I open the text file, there isn't any text inside it" on the other.